# Stream raw audio data from server to client

Tags: audio-streaming

I am working on an audio simulator application for the browser. It is supposed to play a WAV file(or any other raw audio binary format) to the user, but the user is capable of changing certain parameters of the signal in real time and hear the change in the already playing audio file.

The algorithm that changes the sound is proprietary and already has a working solution as a desktop app in Java, but I will have to set this up online. I am looking for a solution where most of this would be done server-side and have the client only send the parameters.

My goal is not to open for example '/something.wav' on server and play it, but to extract the audio data (which I already have) and somehow send that raw audio data to the client to play it. Is this possible and if so what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: It's possible.  Can you elaborate on the "raw" part?  Do you need lossless PCM audio?  Or, is compressed audio fine?  And, what are your latency requirements here?  Is it "live"?  And if so, how live does it need to be?

Comment: It needs to be lossless PCM audio. It is not live, user would upload his lossless file to server, server would read audio data and send that data in chunks to the client to be played. Then during the playing of the file user can modify certain parameters, send those parameters to server, server modifies the signal and from that point on sends the modified signal to client all while the music is playing. Latency is fine, for example if user needs to wait a couple of seconds for the music to "change" based on parameters it is fine.

Comment: Got it, so the audio is live in the sense that it is being manipulating it live and your playing what's streaming back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client, the easiest thing to do is a simple HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio src="https://your-audio-server/some-id" preload="none" controls></audio>
```

The `preload="none"` prevents the audio from being buffered early.  (This is live, so you don't want to be buffering data from the past for seconds or minutes until the user hits play!)

Most browsers support WAV file playback.  Therefore, all you need to do is send a WAV stream live.  Your server should take this PCM input, send the appropriate headers, and then start sending PCM data.  The client will buffer this for a couple seconds and then begin playback.

That is, your server will mux to a live WAV stream and stream that output in realtime to the client.  The client doesn't know or care whether it's receiving a file or a live stream.

Comment: Audio tag can read raw audio data? So I can point the src attribute to my server which simply returns raw data (not the actual "song.wav") and it will begin playing it?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Not raw audio data... it needs a WAV header.  Otherwise, it wouldn't know how many channels, sample rate, bit depth, etc.  But, it's trivial for you to take that raw audio data and add a WAV header.  http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: Isn't it easier then to use the Web Audio API? Then I wouldn't need to bother with headers if it can read just raw data?

Comment: @MichaelMunta No, using the Web Audio API to stream in raw PCM requires you to handle your own buffering and sample rate conversion.  While that route certainly gives you more control in general, I think you'll find it much easier to write the couple lines of code to output the few bytes of header before your samples.

Comment: And how do I implement this "liveness" on the server? I was thinking of having a loop on the client that keeps asking for more chunks of data, but with audio tag I have only one endpoint which I query.

Comment: Client makes HTTP request, server sends WAV header, and then as the server gets more chunks of audio, it just writes them directly to the stream to be sent to client.  That's really all there is to it.  I don't what you plan to use server-side.  I've done this type of project a few times in Node.js, which has a nice streams interface for HTTP requests and responses.  (By the way, if you're interested in licensing some code for this rather than building it yourself, feel free to contact me at brad@audiopump.co.)

Comment: I understand, but how will the audio element behave in that case? What will be its src attribute?

Comment: The `src` attribute is the URL of the stream.  Again, the browser doesn't know or care where the server gets the data it sends.  The browser receives a response to its request and has no way of knowing whether it came from a file or somewhere else.  The server receives a request for `/some-stream` or whatever, and then knows to stream the data for `some-stream`.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I just need to have this audio tag on the client and the server will loop and keep sending chunks? I don't need to keep requesting chunks explicitly on the client?

Comment: That's correct!  The built-in audio player on the client takes care of it, just as it would if it were a file being streamed.

Comment: Hm, but there is an issue with this. I have no way of controlling the rate at which server returns chunks of audio. Seems I need to use Web Audio API and make requests for each chunk. How else would I be able to change the audio signal on the server?

Comment: @MichaelMunta No, that's incorrect.  That's one of the main reasons of using the <audio> tag... the browser handles buffering and flow control.  As it plays, it will put backpressure on the stream, if necessary.  That ends up causing the TCP window size to drop, eventually to zero, telling the server to wait before sending more data.  When the browser is ready for more data, that window size is increased again.

Comment: Do you have any reference links where I can read up more on how audio tag works and how server should return data?

Comment: @MichaelMunta I think what you should do is create a long WAV file, fire up a web server, set up a web page with an audio tag pointing at that WAV file, and observe the interaction between the server and client with Wireshark.  I can't think of any other reference.